# ForEach loop over string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find all last job statuses fro a list of VMs backed up with veeam backup.
Strangely the loop do not go to the next vm. Here is what I do:

```
Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin
$VMlist = "vm1, vm2" 
$VMlist = $VMlist.split(",");
Foreach ($i in $VMlist) {

    foreach($Job in (Get-VBRJob))
{
        $Session = $Job.FindLastSession()
        if(!$Session){continue;}
        $Tasks = $Session.GetTaskSessions()
        $Tasks | ?{$_.Name -eq $VMlist} | %{write-host $_.Name ":" $_.Status}
```

It seems I have a problem in the for each loop, since it stuck and I do not get any output. What is thebest way to iterate over the slit of VMs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `$VMList` array in `$Tasks` not the individual VM `$i`, just change: `{$_.Name -eq $i}`

Also your VM names will include leading spaces, either remove the spaces from your input string `"vm1,vm2"`, or use [`Trim()`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/18/trim-your-strings-with-powershell/) after `Split()`

```
Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin
$VMlist = "vm1,vm2" 
$VMlist = $VMlist.split(",");
foreach ($i in $VMlist) {
    foreach ($Job in (Get-VBRJob)) {
        $Session = $Job.FindLastSession()
        if (!$Session) {continue; }
        $Tasks = $Session.GetTaskSessions()
        $Tasks | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $i} | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Name ":" $_.Status}
    }
}
```